# Why ServiceStack AuthProvider Logout is not working in deployed environment

Tags: servicestack

In our project we are overriding the logout method of Servicestack to remove and delete "ss-tok" cookie.
While this is working on my local machine , in deployed environment I see the ss-tok are still exists in cookie list on calling base.logout(). Therefore next time when  users try to access application, they can sign in without going through login process.

```
`public class SSOAuthProvider : AuthProvider
 {
    public override object Logout(IServiceBase service, Authenticate request)
    {
          return base.Logout(service, request) as AuthenticateResponse;
    }
 }`
```

I am expecting the ss-tok to be cleared on calling Authprovider logout method so that the user are prompted to sign in next time they try access application.

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation of [AuthProvider.LogoutAsync()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthProvider.cs#L111) which removes the  Session and JWT Cookies with:

```cs
service.Request.Response.DeleteSessionCookies();
service.Request.Response.DeleteJwtCookie();
```

Not sure if your older version of ServiceStack has these methods, but [here's the their implementations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/ef61bd48d97db58a6dd42fbe9a5223b81990d9f1/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/SessionExtensions.cs#L351-L364):

```cs
public static void DeleteSessionCookies(this IResponse response)
{
    if (!(response is IHttpResponse httpRes)) return;
    httpRes.Cookies.DeleteCookie(Keywords.SessionId);
    httpRes.Cookies.DeleteCookie(Keywords.PermanentSessionId);
    httpRes.Cookies.DeleteCookie(HttpHeaders.XUserAuthId);
}

public static void DeleteJwtCookie(this IResponse response)
{
    var httpRes = response as IHttpResponse;
    httpRes?.Cookies.DeleteCookie(Keywords.TokenCookie);
    httpRes?.Cookies.DeleteCookie(Keywords.RefreshTokenCookie);
}
```